# Getting the Rendered Font in Chrome in Code

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

We have had some issues with Custom Fonts not rendering on our site and would like to wrap some  assertions around this in our automation test pack.

Can I get the rendered font value (New Times Roman) if my custom font (TheRichRamily) is not available in code, I am using Selenium/C# and can execute JS at runtime.

[Rendered Fonts.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3DLD.png)

Comment: Try to paraphrase your question or add details, what do you mean get font value?

Comment: Paraphrase or add details? Not sure what that means. Font value is the value held in the Font. ie Helvetica.